# Iterate with different from default sorting class STL set

Tags: c++, stl, set

Could you please tell me why this code doesn't work as expected.
It should print persons in reversed order but it doesn't for some reason.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

class Person
{
    friend class AgeSorter;
    friend class AgeInversedSorter;

private:
    int m_age;

public:
    int GetAge() const
    {
        return m_age;
    }

    int operator == (const Person& otherPerson) const
    {
        return m_age - otherPerson.m_age;
    }

    Person(const Person& otherPerson)
    {
        m_age = otherPerson.m_age;
        std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    Person(int age) : m_age(age)
    {

    }
};

class AgeSorter
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Person& first, const Person& second) const
    {
        return first.m_age > second.m_age;
    }
};

class AgeInversedSorter
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Person& first, const Person& second) const
    {
        return first.m_age < second.m_age;
    }
};

typedef std::set<Person, AgeSorter>                     Persons;
typedef Persons::iterator                               PersonsDefaultIterator;
typedef std::set<Person, AgeInversedSorter>::iterator   PersonsInversedAgeIterator;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Persons persons;
    Person person1(20);
    Person person2(10);

    persons.insert(person1);
    persons.insert(person2);

    std::cout << "Output using default iterator:" << std::endl;
    for (PersonsDefaultIterator iterator = persons.begin();
        iterator != persons.end();
        iterator++)
    {
        std::cout << iterator->GetAge() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Output using inversed iterator:" << std::endl;
    PersonsInversedAgeIterator iterator = persons.begin();
    for (PersonsInversedAgeIterator iterator = persons.begin();
        iterator != persons.end();
        iterator++)
    {
        std::cout << iterator->GetAge() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Press <Enter> to quit." << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

As i see default sorter is called upon inserting of elements, however no sorter functionoids called upon iterating through collections in first way (its perfectly ok) and in second way...

Comment: Yes, i'm learning c++ set container type and just checking whether STL works good with different iterators. And its strange to see it doesn't (or i probably don't understood it yet)

Comment: Ordering happens on insertion. You have only one set there, ordered in  no inverse way.

Comment: Thank you! That's it! As i understood code in inversed order is compiled just to make generic algorythms work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code is **wrong**.

```
PersonsInversedAgeIterator iterator = persons.begin();
```

The return type of `persons.begin()` is `std::set<Person, AgeSorter>::iterator`, and the type of `PersonsInversedAgeIterator` is `std::set<Person, AgeInversedSorter>::iterator`.

Second, `AgeInversedSorter` is *default* order of STL (`std::less`).. your `AgeSorter` is *reverse* order of STL (`std::greater<>`).

So, you should edit `Sorter`s into your expected order, and use proper containers with proper iterators.

Comment: @drweb86 Maybe two iterator types are the same by accident; standard doesn't specify STL container's iterator type. it can be anything if it can satisfy standard... (for example, `std::vector<>::iterator` may be just pointers.)

Comment: Ok, ikh, thank you soo much! Probably that compile relaxation is to make it more compartible with generic algorythms.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that:

`PersonsInversedAgeIterator` are same type `PersonsDefaultIterator`, so you doesn't get error with your code.

To see the difference order, you have to use 2 sets:

```
std::set<Person, AgeSorter> persons = {Person(20), Person(10)};
std::set<Person, AgeInversedSorter> reversePersons = {Person(20), Person(10)};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/IT7lwM).

Comment: Jarod42, thank you for showing better way for iterating via items and creating collections of items then it was in my sample. I thought foreach from c# will never appear in c++ for hidden iterators usage!!!

Comment: @drweb86 range-based for loop and initializer list for custom types (`persons = { Person(20), Person(10) }`) are C++11 features. They are pretty awesome, but it could be harmful if you're newbie on C++ and didn't study even C++98, which is old version of C++.